# How to take the index of a content in ListView.builder and have a setstate() for every click depending on the index of the list

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Here is the related code to help what i mean :

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: recentList1.length,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        var recent = recentList1[index];
        return InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => p1Read(contents: recent),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0, vertical: 8.0),
            child: pt1Card(contents: recent),
          ),
        );
      },
    )
```

I have 3 items inside recentlist1.length. And im trying to set a variable to a number based on which either of the inkwells are clicked, Since there are 3 there will be 3 inkwells in the screen. And im trying to setstate a variable to 1 if the first inkwell is clicked, 2 when the second inkwell is clicked and set the variable to 3 when the third inkwell is clicked. How would i go aout in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you right.

Could you not just take the index + 1?

```
    ListView.builder(
        itemCount: recentList1.length,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        var recent = recentList1[index];
        return InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            setState((){
                YOUR_VARIABLE = index + 1;
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0, vertical: 8.0),
            child: pt1Card(contents: recent),
          ),
        );
      },
    )
```